# create a javascript to compute and display the roots of the quadratic equation ax2 + bx + c = 0

Tags: javascript

I meet a problem like when I try to enter a number like 1,1,0 for a,b,c the x1 should show x1 =0. x2 = -1, but it doesn't work.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function solve()
{
   var formObj = document.getElementById("linEq");
   var a = formObj.a.value;
   var b = formObj.b.value;
   var c = formObj.c.value;
   var det = 2*a;

   formObj.x1.value = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2) - 4*a*c)/det;
   formObj.x2.value = (-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2) - 4*a*c)/det;

}
//  -->
</script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #add8e6;">
<h2>Linear System Solver</h2>

<p>Input the coefficients into the linear system:</p>
<form id="linEq" action="#">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="text" size="4" name="a" /><b>x^2</b></td> <td>+</td>
 <td><input type="text" size="4" name="b" /><b>x</b></td> <td>+</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="4" name="c" /></td> <td>=</td>
 <td><b>0</b></td></tr>
</table>

<p><input type="button" value="Solve it" onclick="solve()" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" /> </p>

<p>Solution: <b>x1</b> = 
<input type="text" size="10" name="x1" />
    <b>x2</b> = 
<input type="text" size="10" name="x2" />
</p>
</form>
```

I don't know where the mistake is, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Always check your browser console before asking why something isn't working as expected. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';' @ HTML line 11`

Comment: Alright, got it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot to add a paranthesis at the end of the lines with formObj.x1.value and formObj.x2.value. Also consider including validation of input parameters. As negative coeficients in the SQRT will return NAN answers for x1 and x2.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function solve() {
      var formObj = document.getElementById("linEq");
      var a = Number(formObj.a.value);
      var b = Number(formObj.b.value);
      var c = Number(formObj.c.value);
      var det = 2 * a;

      formObj.x1.value = (-1 * b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / det;
      formObj.x2.value = (-1 * b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / det;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #add8e6;">
  <h2>Linear System Solver</h2>

  <p>Input the coefficients into the linear system:</p>
  <form id="linEq" action="#">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" size="4" name="a" /><b>x^2</b></td>
        <td>+</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="4" name="b" /><b>x</b></td>
        <td>+</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="4" name="c" /></td>
        <td>=</td>
        <td><b>0</b></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <p><input type="button" value="Solve it" onclick="solve()" />
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" /> </p>

    <p>Solution: <b>x1</b> =
      <input type="text" size="10" name="x1" />
      <b>x2</b> =
      <input type="text" size="10" name="x2" />
    </p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```